# Bootstrap column wraps with container-fluid (nesting with container)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

the following example: http://www.bootply.com/ygN8uoWw7p# tries to create a layout with some text on the left and some buttons and a more complex thing on the right (which should be right aligned)

I know that container and container-fluid should not be nested. But as far as I understand it, the reason is for padding.

What I want to accomplish is the element1 and element2 also stay on the same line (row) and are not wrapped. As you can see in the example the elements shouljd have more than enough space to be rendered on the same line.

Can you please explain why they are wrapped. I assume that container-fluid creates the problem? 
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Element 1 and Element 2 are on the line as your your text on the left. It is the button that is pushing those elements down.

Move your button like this and you will see:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">On the left</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2">El1</div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">El2</div>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-original-title="" title=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> </button></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```